# Merge [languages] into [programming-languages]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

I see no reason why anyone needs to use [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) instead of [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages).

1. A question asking about a language such as English, French, etc. is off-topic anyway.
2. [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) is more specific and has a tag wiki unlike [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages).
3. [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) is used over 10x as much as [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages).

Therefore, [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) should be merged into [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages).

Comment: What about detecting languages from a given text, using code?

Comment: This question does *not* use `languages` in the sense of programming languages: [How to correctly choose languages support in Windows Phone 8 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24114038). There are more examples. The tag is misused for `programming-languages` on many posts, but that doesn't make it a suitable merge.

Comment: @MartijnPeters You're correct.  I didn't think of that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it may need a different fix to a merge — from a quick look, there are definitely a few questions that are using it as a synonym to [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization), e.g:

- [How can I add several languages to my app? not the description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763697/how-can-i-add-several-languages-to-my-app-not-the-description)
- [Get Item in all languages in which it has a version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915696/sitecore-7get-item-in-all-languages-in-which-it-has-a-version)
- [How to create a table in Oracle 11g with the list of language codes based on util_i18n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865905/how-to-create-a-table-in-oracle-11g-with-the-list-of-language-codes-based-on-uti)

(Arguably that's not incorrect either, if [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) has no wiki)

Might need to look at it on a case-by-case basis & retag the questions with [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) or [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) as needed.